# How to get the FileField from ModelFrom in django views

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform, filefield

I currently want to send some data to my database by doing the following: Sending a document to the database and each document has a foreign key from the user table i.e. each document is a reference to an author(from another table) but it will be bad for the user to get all the users in the system and choosing one of them, I want the author assignment to be performed in the views. So as a summary I want to get fields from the form in views. I found a corresponding question and tip at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635957/setting-the-field-value-of-a-form-in-view-py),  but the only issue here being that a file was not inlcuded in his model but on mine yes. Snipets of my files below;

**models.py**

```py
class UploadedDocuments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        TheUsers,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    document = models.FileField(
        verbose_name='Document',
        upload_to=f'documents/%Y/',
        null=True,
    )
    plagiarism_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    serialised_content = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='Uploaded On',
        auto_now_add=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Document"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Documents'
```

**Views.py**

```py
def upload(request):
    form = UploadedDocumentsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
           form_stack = form.save(commit = False)
           form.user = request.user
           form_stack.serialised_content = "bala"
           form_stack.plagiarism_status = 'Hello'
           form_stack.save()
           return redirect("results")
```

> function which is constantly telling me invalid.

**forms.py**

```py
class UploadedDocumentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedDocuments
        fields = ['document', 'user', 'plagiarism_status', 'serialised_content']
        widgets = {
            'document': forms.FileInput(
                attrs = {
                    'class': 'drop-zone__input',
                    'id': 'file',
                    'accept': '.doc, .docx, .txt',
                    'required': True,
                }
            ),
            'user': forms.Select(
                attrs = {

                }
            ),
            'plagiarism_status': forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    'hidden': True,
                }
            ),
            'serialised_content': forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    'hidden': True,
                }
            )
        }
```

**my template file**

```html
    <form action="{% url 'upload' %}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="drop-zone w-50">
        <span class="drop-zone__prompt text-center h3">
            Drops file here
        </span>
            {{ form.document }}
            {{ form.user }}
            {{ form.serialised_content }}
            {{ form.plagiarism_status }}
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white btn-outline-success
                p-4 px-5 w-lg-25 w-md-50 w-sm-50 text-capitalize5 my-5">
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-sync px-3"></i>
                Upload
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Any suggestion on how this could be done will be helpful.

Comment: you can change form instance after save the form. `form.instance.user = request.user`

Comment: The issue here is that I can't save the form since it doesn't validate. Even upon removing the check(`form.is_valid()`) still getting that error. Can you suggest something else?

Answer (score 0):

add blank and none to your user of UploadedDocuments model:

```py
class UploadedDocuments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        TheUsers,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    ...
```

Comment: The blank can't go! I need to reference each document upload. I think the issue with my model should be in the view or form not models

Comment: yes. the blank is only for saving it with form. You should remove the user from the form, save the instance with a blank user, and then change the user of doc. also, you can save the form manually without `.save()` and check the validity manually.